# For a user defined python type, have `a+b+c+d` do `summation(a,b,c,d)` instead of `((a+b)+c)+d`

Tags: python, delayed-execution

I have a type `Foo` for which calling `summation(a,b,c,d)` is much more efficient than performing additions `a+b+c+d`.  Yet, it's way nicer to just write `a+b+c+d`.

A solution, as far as I understand, is to write a wrapper type `DelayedSum` so that `Foo.__add__(a, b)` will return `DelayedSum([a, b])` and `DelayedSum.__add__` does something similar. Then I need to provide for the calculation to be performed each time the object of type `DelayedSum` is used. It means that I need to define all the "magic" operators

```
class DelayedSum:
    ...
    def __len__(self):
        foo = summation(*self.foo_list) # this will be repeated everywhere, write decorator?
        return len(foo)  
    def __getattr__(self, value):
        ...
```

Also, I'm pretty sure this will start to get a bit awkward if someone starts using `y = a+b+c` and check `y` is of a given type or tries `y.bar = 2`. And I'm pretty much sure I forget a few issues.

Is there a standard way to proceed and/or a package for it?  I'm certainly not the first one to need that but I have trouble to find the relevant info.